# Excel VBA submit a Microsoft Form

Tags: excel, vba, forms, internet-explorer

I'm trying to submit a Microsoft Form with some values from a VBA script so that when something specific happens throughout the day, I can view all occurrences at once. I've got it opening up in IE, putting the value in the box, and then submitting, but the value does not seem to save.

I'm wondering if there is something different I can do when setting the questions value

```
Sub Init_app3()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim URL As String
Dim question As Object
Dim btnGo As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
URL = "https://forms.office.com/r/mvT5hD1RRT"
IE.navigate (URL)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

Set question = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius")(0)
With question
.value = "MALE"
End With

Set btnGo = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button-content")(0)
delay 5
With btnGo
.Click
End With
delay 5


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
 
Exit Sub


End Sub
```

Comment: You need a timed loop until the input box is present after page load. I would also use .Focus on the element before setting the .Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the issue when I test with my own Microsoft Form. It seems that `question.value` can't set a value to the input box effectively. In this situation, you can simulate user input using `SendKeys` to set value to the input box.

You can change the block of code setting question value into the following, I have tested it and it can set and save the value correctly:

```
Set question = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius")(0)
question.Focus
SendKeys ("MALE")
```

Comment: Any idea on how to accomplish it without the sendkeys? Trying to now make the window invisible.