# VBA submit MS Form: input value has been filled but not successfully submited

Tags: excel, vba, forms, internet-explorer

I am using VBA in excel to submit a MS form. It could fill the values to text inputs but after submit, this question is still blank. Any thoughts?

```
Dim emailDomain As Variant
Dim URL As String        
        Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
        IE.Visible = True
        URL = "https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=Aq5v9jZdW0m_4Him_5-ObrQJR7r8UGdPhwKFE494ioxUOEg4M1Q5STRGSzk5Q1VPMTJPRUNLMk5IMi4u"
        IE.navigate (URL)

        While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Wend             
        
        IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius")(0).Value = "currentUserEmailAddress"

        delay 5
        IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button-content")(0).Click
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Before submit, the value has been filled correctly

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I met this kind of issue before. You can also refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68088336/excel-vba-submit-a-microsoft-form/68096105#68096105).

The root cause of the issue is `.Value` can't set the value effectively. In this situation, you can simulate user input using `SendKeys` to set value to the input box.

Sample code:

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius")(0).Focus
SendKeys ("currentUserEmailAddress")
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is the worst solution you can choose (if there are others) and actually this is not the solution to the issue the OP has, as the input box got filled out properly (as he writes in his question).

Comment: @Pᴇʜ The input box will get filled but the backend can't receive the value if you use `.Value` to fill the box in Microsoft Form. If you have made a test with Microsoft Form, you'll find `SendKeys` will make the backend to receive the value. Besides, I can say that you haven't tested at all nor opened the website in IE11. Op is using **IE**, you'll find that the three dot menu button doesn't exist if you open it in IE11, and op's way to get the submit button is nothing wrong in IE11.

Comment: It does work, see my answer. True I missed that the dotted menu disappears in IE11 but still setting the value with `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius")(0).Value = "currentUserEmailAddress"` and sending it with `IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-theme-primary-background office-form-theme-button office-form-bottom-button button-control light-background-button __submit-button__")(0).Click` works perfectly. There's no need for using `SendKeys`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ You don't get my point. Yes, your code can click the button and op's code can also click the button, so finding the button class is not the problem. My point is the problem existing on **form owner receiving the data**: The form is created by the owner. If we fill the form, the owner will receive the data in the backend like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPDf9.png. If you use `.Value` to fill the input, in the backend it will show **an empty result** like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDKYE.png. But if we use `SendKeys`, it will show the data we fill in the backend.

Comment: That's what op mean *It could fill the values to text inputs but after submit, this question is still blank*. You can have a try by yourself by clicking ["Create my own form"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgp0.png) after you submit the form. Creating your form then automating in VBA, you'll reproduce the issue and see what I mean. @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Yes as Yu said, from front end everything looks fine. But when you view the result of the forms, it did not really take the value you filled with method .Value @Pᴇʜ

Answer (score 1):

This `<div class="button-content">Absenden</div>` is not a button but the actual button starts with `<button` so this is what you need to look for and click on.

```html
<button class="office-form-theme-primary-background office-form-theme-button office-form-bottom-button button-control light-background-button __submit-button__" title="Absenden" role="button">
    <div class="button-content">Absenden</div>
</button>
```

In order to click the send button you can use something like

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-theme-primary-background office-form-theme-button office-form-bottom-button button-control light-background-button __submit-button__")(0).Click
```

after you have set the value of the textbox with

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("office-form-question-textbox office-form-textfield-input form-control office-form-theme-focus-border border-no-radius")(0).Value = "currentUserEmailAddress"
```

[image]